# I can't load model FaceNet it said ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I just want to use the FaceNet model in this link
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-face-recognition-system-using-facenet-in-keras-and-an-svm-classifier/

First, Step I can't do it.It fail to load model

Code

```
# example of loading the keras facenet model
from keras.models import load_model
# load the model
model = load_model('facenet_keras.h5')
# summarize input and output shape
print(model.inputs)
print(model.outputs)
```

Error:

```
2021-05-31 12:28:26.125652: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\work\ฝึกงาน\faceNet.py", line 4, in <module>
    model = load_model('facenet_keras.h5')
  File "C:\Users\godja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\saving\save.py", line 201, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects,
  File "C:\Users\godja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 180, in load_model_from_hdf5
    model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config,
  File "C:\Users\godja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\saving\model_config.py", line 59, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\godja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\layers\serialization.py", line 159, in deserialize
    return generic_utils.deserialize_keras_object(
  File "C:\Users\godja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 668, in deserialize_keras_object
    deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(
  File "C:\Users\godja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2332, in from_config
    functional.reconstruct_from_config(config, custom_objects))
  File "C:\Users\godja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 1274, in reconstruct_from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)
  File "C:\Users\godja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 1256, in process_layer
    layer = deserialize_layer(layer_data, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\godja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\layers\serialization.py", line 159, in deserialize
    return generic_utils.deserialize_keras_object(
  File "C:\Users\godja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 668, in deserialize_keras_object
    deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(
  File "C:\Users\godja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 1001, in from_config
    function = cls._parse_function_from_config(
  File "C:\Users\godja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 1053, in _parse_function_from_config
    function = generic_utils.func_load(
  File "C:\Users\godja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 783, in func_load
    code = marshal.loads(raw_code)
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

Comment: Where is 'facenet_keras.h5' on your machine, is it in the directory you're running from?
What version of python are you running, should be > 3.x for this model

Comment: @queste I using version 3.9.5 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pwQ3H4aJ8a6yyJHZkTwtjcL4wYWQb7bn
This is a file model. yes It in directory

Comment: Sorry I meant the other way, it's possible that this model was trained on an older version of python and libraries - that's a common problem with using pre-trained models. If you know what you're doing, you can try to recreate the model's architercture and use its pre-trained weights only. 
If you're learning now, then look for another pre-trained model to save you the hassle :)

Comment: In the comments of the article you linked, it states "the tutorial works with Python 3.6, TensorFlow 2.0, and MTCNN v0.1.0.
Ensure you are using Keras 2.3"

Comment: I can't remodel because when I use ```pip install tensorFlow == 2.0``` It said can't find this version. Do you have any success? @queste

Comment: @JackyTeerapat, you get above issue is due to you are using python version 3.9.5. To use Tensorflow 2.0, the compatible python version should be between 3.5 to 3.7. Thanks!

Comment: @JackyTeerapat, Did you solve it? please update the the answer if so.

Answer (score 0):

```
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
```

This works for me.

before implementing you just need to install one dependency using the bellow code in your terminal:

```
#pip install keras_facenet
```